# Boolean Functions Implemented by Multiplexers

Tags: reference-request

Electrical engineers often use multiplexers to implement Boolean functions. What is the correct technical term for this model of computation? Is it Decision Tree model or is there another name?

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail?

Comment: You are using multiplexers ( relays if you like) to implement Boolean functions instead of logic gates. Engineers use this technique to build circuits with large truth tables because it is easy to just hardwire the values of the truth table into the input lines of the multiplexer. So what do you call this method of computation, is it relay logic, decision tree ( because the multiplexers are in the tree arrangement for any N input) ?

Comment: You can call it a multiplexer if you wish, though truth table might be more common. It is a rather boring model of computation, since all functions have the same complexity.

Comment: What do you mean " all the functions have the same complexity" ?

Comment: All functions of length $n$ have the same complexity, or rather, there is no meaningful way to define a complexity measure for functions in this model.

Comment: Why is there no "meaningful way" to define a complexity measure?

Comment: Since you are describing a function via its truth table, which always has the same size.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for your last comment ?

Comment: I think the issue might be that you have never defined what a multiplexer is. Perhaps you could update your question by including this information. Don't assume readers here know anything about multiplexers.

Comment: Are you telling me that you have never seen how to implement a Boolean function using multiplexers ?

Comment: That's exactly what I am telling you. If you want to get any help on this site, you'd better explain your question to the general computer science audience.

Comment: OK, thank you . I will update my question later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no specific name for it, just several methods, c.p. [this website](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/multiplexer/index.html)
Note that it's quite simple to e.g. implement all 2-input logic functions with a 4 input 
 1 output mux, by connecting the inputs to the address/select lines, and applying the constants 0/1 to the data inputs. (This actually transforms the MUX into a Lookup table (LUT))

Comment: Thank you for replying , but this doesn't answer my question. Dig deeper :-)

Comment: It absolutely answers your question. Your question is "What is the name of this thing?" and the answer given is "It doesn't have a name." I've no idea if that's the correct answer, but it's certainly _an_ answer.

Comment: OK , you and Yuval are professional computer scientists, if you all don't know the answer than " with high probability" there is no answer. I withdraw the question.